# When are two html DOMS are equal?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Are DOMs equal if they are not in the same order but have the same number of elements for every type?

like this:

```
First DOM Element ="<div>
                     <img/>
                     <span/>
                     <div>
                       <img/>
                     </div>
                    </div>";

Second DOM Element = "<div>
                       <img/>
                       <img/>
                       <span>
                         <div/>
                       </span>
                      </div>";
```

In this practically sample when I have the same number of elements type,does the order of the elements is matter, are the DOM still equal?

Thanks

Comment: I think you've answered your own question - if using `isEqualNode` then the answer is "no, they are not equal".

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough with my question,  my purpose was to understand when are two DOMS equal and in what conditions, that way I removed the isEqualNode function from my question

Comment: If you don't define your method of comparing, then we cannot answer the question. Are you just counting the number of elements? Or are you comparing the structure of all child elements? If you just ask "are DOMs equal" we cannot answer if we don't know the comparator.

Comment: @MattJones thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 4):

From the [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-equals):

> A node 'A' equals a node 'B' if all of the following conditions are true:
>
> [other conditions removed for brevity]
>
> • Each child of 'A' equals the child of 'B' at the identical index.

So if the child elements are not ordered the same, they are not considered equal.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Jones, this is what I have look for.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing element nodes that have child elements, the `.isEqualNode()` is applied recursively to pairs of child nodes at corresponding indexes, and each child node must be equal to the other.

So, the DOM subtree structures must look exactly the same. That is, the value of `A.childNodes[0]` must be equal (under the rules of `.isEqualNode()`) to the value of `B.childNodes[0]`, and so on.

Note that there are other rules for `.isEqualNode()` too: the attributes must be the same with the same values, obviously the node types must be the same, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't equal because firstElement is:

1 div

|_ 1 img

|_ 1 span

|_ 1 div

..etc..

The second one instead contains:

1 div

|_ 2 img <--- Here is already different

..etc...

The function [isEqualNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode) returns `true` when they have the same type, defining characteristics (for elements, this would be their ID, number of children, and so forth), its attributes match, and so on.

See following snippet please:

```js
let divList  = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

function test(p1, p2) {
  console.log("div " + p1 + " equals div " + p2 + ": " + divList[p1].isEqualNode(divList[p2]));
}

test(0, 0);
test(0, 1);
test(0, 2);
```

```html
<div>This is the first element.</div>
<div>This is the second element.</div>
<div>This is the first element.</div>
```

I hope it was clear, bye.